# Where is this port number http://localhost:52432/ specified when running an ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm playing around with ASP.NET MVC and I just loaded up an empty project and ran it and the URL in my browser is `http://localhost:52432/`.  Where is the 52432 port number specified?

Thanks in advance for your help, I'm going to start researching this question right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your project file

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>1424</DevelopmentServerPort>
```

Answer (score 2):

The setting is stored in your project file which is XML, to access the setting from the UI, right click on your project in the solution explorer and choose properties. In the properties dialog on the left side there is a tab selector, choose Web.

In the Web properties in the Servers section you will see a radio button for 'Use Development Server' and by default it will probably be set to Auto-Assign port, you can change the setting there and choose an explicit port or change to IIS.

Again - Project-Properties-Web